# Python process doesn't write stdout to file until execution is finished

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am starting a new process and redirecting its stdout to a text file. I am want to read the progress the processing from the file, however the file stays empty until the process finishes executing. Can you explain this behavior and if there is a work around it ?

```
p = Process(target=foo, args=(a,))
p.start()

def foo(a):
    sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")
    print("test")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: You have to use unbuffered output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is to add *flush=True* to your `print` statement.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import time


def foo(a):
    sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")
    print("test", flush=True)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
    p.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

@azelcer Is correct I need to use unbuffered output, however text i/o can' be unbuffered in python so the best way is to use a buffer of size one so the output will be flushed to the file every time a line is printed.

```
p = Process(target=foo, args=(a,))
p.start()

def foo(a):
    sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w", 1)
    print("test")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Do you realize that the reason for buffering is to avoid the performance penalty of writing to output every time? If that’s what you absolutely want, fine, but something to consider.